# After clearing config cache i got database access denied error

Tags: laravel, apache, multi-tenant, laravel-artisan

The site is not accessible after clearing cache

Edit:

> I tried to access the database via command line using that user and I
>   can  fully access the database.

I issued the command

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

after that the site is not accessible

**Expected behavior**

The site should be fine because I only clear the cache

**Information**

```
hyn/multi-tenant version: 5.*
laravel version: 5.4
database driver and version: mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24
webserver software and version: Apache/2.4.37
php version: PHP 7.1.26
```

Error log

```
[11-Jan-2019 06:21:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[11-Jan-2019 06:21:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[11-Jan-2019 06:21:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[11-Jan-2019 06:21:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[16-Jan-2019 08:33:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[16-Jan-2019 08:33:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[16-Jan-2019 08:33:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[16-Jan-2019 08:34:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:00:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:00:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:00:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:00:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:00:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:01:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:01:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:05:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:05:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:06:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:17:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:18:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:18:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:18:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:19:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:49:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 00:49:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:20:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:33:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:34:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:37:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:37:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:37:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:38:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:39:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:39:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:39:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:39:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:39:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:40:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71$
[17-Jan-2019 01:40:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php7
```

Laravel Log

http://prntscr.com/m89o1l

Comment: what error are you getting check logs?

Comment: check your `.env` file.

Comment: updated the question with error log